# How can I depict this function with numpy.sum?

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to calculate this sum

[image]

using numpy.sum - how can I do that?

Phi is a function that takes one parameter, y and x are vectors of length i

Answer (score 1):

Start with x and y as numpy arrays

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 3])
y = np.array([4, 5, 6])
```

You will pass in the array,

```
r = y - (theta_0*x + theta_1)
```

Define your function, and hopefully you can do vectorized operations within the function, but whatever, the function needs to return a numpy vector if you want to use numpy.sum

```
def Phi(r):
    a = r*r    # and example operation
    return a   # returning a numpy array
```

Then call the function and sum:

```
R = Phi(r).sum()
```